# Confusion about asymptotic distribution of the MLE and of the MAP

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics, fisher-information, point-estimation

It's well known that the MLE $\hat{\theta}$ maximizes $f(y\mid\theta)$ and under regularity conditions has asymptotic distribution
$$N\left(\theta, \frac{I(\theta)}{J^2(\theta)} \right)$$ where $I(\theta)=Var(E[\partial\ell'(y_i,\theta)])$ and $J(\theta)=-E[\partial^2\ell(y_i,\theta)]$(for simplicity I treat the single parameter case).

the MAP estimate gives $\theta$ a prior density and seeks to maximize $f(\theta\mid y)$. It can also be shown that $f(\theta\mid y)$ in the limit converges to
$$N(\hat{\theta}, -\partial^2\ell(\theta\mid y))|_{\theta=\hat{\theta}})$$
where $\hat{\theta}$ denotes the mean of the posterior distribution, ie the MAP. Can I use this result to attain the asymptotic distribution of the MAP, similarly to the MLE? I thought it might have something to do with conjugate distributions (about which I know little)? It would already be very helpful if this were true in a special case, ie the normal case.

Answer (score 4):

Let $g(\theta)$ be the prior distributionfor $\theta$. Let $\mathcal L_n$ be the log-likelhood of the sample,

$$\mathcal L_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln f(y_i \mid \theta)$$

The **MLE** maximizes just $\mathcal L_n$, or equivalently $(1/n)\mathcal L_n$.

The **MAP** maximizes (by considering the monotonic logarithmic transformation) $\ln g(\theta) + \mathcal L_n$, so the f.o.c. is

$$\hat \theta_{MAP}: \frac{g'(\hat \theta_{MAP})}{g(\hat \theta_{MAP})}+\frac{\partial \mathcal L_n(\hat \theta_{MAP})}{\partial \theta} = 0.$$

But, then we also have

$$\hat \theta_{MAP}: \frac 1n \left[\frac{g'(\hat \theta_{MAP})}{g(\hat \theta_{MAP})}+\frac{\partial \mathcal L_n(\hat \theta_{MAP})}{\partial \theta} \right]= 0$$

$$\implies \hat \theta_{MAP}:  \frac 1n \frac{g'(\hat \theta_{MAP})}{g(\hat \theta_{MAP})}+\frac 1n\frac{\partial \mathcal L_n(\hat \theta_{MAP})}{\partial \theta} = 0.$$

But this implies that as $n \to \infty$ the first term goes to zero, because it is not some sum  that increases as sample size increases, and so the **MAP** will become stochastically equivalent to the **MLE**. Intuitively, as we increase the size of the sample, the prior information embodied in $g(\theta)$ becomes negligible, compared to the information contained in the ever-increasing sample.